# Can we automate PWA desktop app using selenium/appium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-desktop

Can we automate PWA desktop app using selenium/appium? If yes, which driver is required?

Answer (score 0):

Well in general a PWA app is a webpage so automation should be possible. I would say you first need to have the app installed on your maschine and then give it a go with WinAppDriver.

Here is also a resource for it https://testautomationu.applitools.com/winappdriver-tutorial/